# Mass Absorption coefficient with photon energy (Gamma ray)

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics

We did an experiment for Gamma ray absorption and 
we used Pb as the material (density of $11.35 g/cm^3$).

I am trying to find the corresponding photon energy for $\mu_m=0.087$ But I couldnt find it anywhere. Can anyone help please

Comment: what would $\mu_m$ be?

Comment: @france95 its just the mass absorption coefficiant

Comment: Does this [NIST database](https://www.nist.gov/pml/x-ray-mass-attenuation-coefficients) help you?